# Is it ever legal in the UK not to have two brakes on a bike?

Tags: brakes, regional, uk, legal

When using a bike on a road in the UK, is it ever legal not to have separate brakes on the front and back wheels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. A fixed wheel does not need two, it needs only one (on the non-fixed, presumably the front, wheel).

Two separate and independent bracking systems, one per wheel, are required, but as the [CTC](http://www.ctc.org.uk/DesktopDefault.aspx?TabID=4073) say

> Apart from saying that a brake that
>   acts directly on a pneumatic tyre
>   shall not be deemed to be in efficient
>   working order, these regulations do
>   not define how the brakes are operated
>   (by hands, feet or maybe even the
>   teeth?) or how they work. A lot of
>   words are nevertheless devoted to
>   wheels that cannot rotate
>   independently of the pedals (i.e. no
>   freewheel), the effect of which is
>   that a fixed wheel drive counts as a
>   braking system – on that wheel or
>   wheels.

Note also that, when sold, European regulations dictate that it should be left-hand rear, right-hand front.

Comment: So the answer is, in fact, no - given that the fixie is acting as a brake?

Comment: If you think that in normal terminology a wheel is a brake, then no. But while legally a fixed's mechanism is considered to be a braking system, to most users of the language it wouldn't generally fall under what a normal reading of the original question would mean as a brake, i.e. a system of levers, cables and pads.

Comment: We're arguing semantics - but the problem I have is that the answer is misleading in that its only legal *because* the back wheel is (in effect) a brake. So the answer is still no. Doesn't really matter that its not a brake in the sense of something that has cables and levers and pads (a back pedal brake would also not be a "brake" if we take that definition). Yes, you explain why but I still disagree with the answer starting "Yes" when in fact the answer is No, but the definition of "brake" means that a fixie only needs one rim brake (or similar)

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure on the legal standing on actually *using* the bike on the road - I think it extends to retailers legally having to sell bikes with brakes, and a bell too I seem to remember.

Comment: and reflectors on pedals!